# How to get length of int from user input in java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the length of characters that the user enters. If the user enters a string with length less than 5 or greater than 5 then it should say "Enter a valid 5 digit number". If the length is 5 then I want it to go on the next question, but for some reason it's not working. Thanks!

```
package Hw;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Library {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int  cardnumber = 0;
int age;
int item = 0;
int overdue = 0;

int fine = item * overdue;

int length = length(Integer.toString(cardnumber));

Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);



System.out.println("Enter Card Number: ");
cardnumber = Keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Age: ");
        age = Keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Item Type (Book = 1, Magazine = 2, Dvd = 3): ");
        item = Keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter The Amount Of Days The Item Has Been Overdue");
overdue = Keyboard.nextInt();

if (length == 5)
{
System.out.println(cardnumber);
}
if (length > 5 || length < 5)
{
System.out.println("Enter A Valid 5 Digit Number");
}



if (item == 1)
{
fine = (int) (overdue * 0.50);
}

else if (item == 2)
        {
            fine = (int) (overdue * 0.25);
        }

    else if (item == 3)
        {
        fine = (int) (overdue * 1.50);
        }



if (age > 5 || age < 18)
{
fine = (int) 1.00;
}


if (age > 70)
{
fine = 0;
}


else if(age > 18 || age < 70)
{

if(overdue < 5)
System.out.println("Days Overdue "+ overdue);
}

else
{
fine = (int) 5.00;
}


/*else if (age < 6 || age > 17)
{
fine = (int) 1.00;
}
*/



System.out.println("Card Number "+ cardnumber);



System.out.println("Age "+ age);

//  System.out.println("Days overdue "+ overdue);

System.out.println("Fine "+ fine);

//  System.out.println("Fine adjustment reason "+ )


if(item == 1)
{
System.out.println("item Book");
}

else if(item == 2)
{
System.out.println("item Magazine");
}

else if(item == 3)
{
System.out.println("item Dvd");
}

else if(item <1 || item >3)
{
System.out.println("Invalid Information");
}   
}

private static int length(String string) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to recalculate `length` after reading it as a value. Currentl it'll always be 0

Comment: Why not just check if it is in between 10000 and 99999?

Comment: You could take the opposite approach by taking the value as a string and simply checking the `length()` if it's good then parse it to an int.

Comment: Is `00123` a valid 5-digit card number?

Comment: You should probably put a loop around the card number so you won't proceed until they do it correctly. You don't want to remove that line but rather move it to the appropriate place.

Comment: If a card number beginning with 0's is valid i.e. `00023` then the zeros will be lost when it's converted to an int, so entering the zeros would be pointless once converted and a minimum length check would be unnecessary. So @AndrewLi suggestion seems most logical, continue asking `while (cardNumber < 10000 || cardNumber > 99999)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main concept should be working with String instead of Integer, by that approach it is much easier and quicker to check the user's input length.

I would recommend to change the code as follows:
Change that line:

```
int length = length(Integer.toString(cardnumber));
```

to:

```
String length = Integer.toString(cardnumber);
```

Another change is the following lines:

```
if (length == 5)
{
System.out.println(cardnumber);
} 
if (length > 5 || length < 5)
{
System.out.println("Enter A Valid 5 Digit Number");
}
```

Should be replaced to:

```
while(length != 5) {
    System.out.println("Enter A Valid 5 Digit Number");
    cardnumber = Keyboard.nextInt();
    length = Integer.toString(cardnumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your question as asked would be, how to implement this method:

```
private static int length(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

What you want is to look at the length() method built into the Java string object.

In the interest of being helpful - it seems like there are some other misconceptions reflected in your code.  Apologies if I'm reading too much into the code you provided, but it appears you need to think about what the line

```
int length = length(Integer.toString(cardnumber));
```

really does - or, alternatively, what value `cardnumber` stores at the time your running that line.

Comment: There still seems to be a problem as the outcome is always saying enter a valid 5 digit number. Thanks

Comment: Then i assume your only change was to add the implementation of length(). As I noted, the code you showed has problems unrelated to your question and you'll have to fix them as well to see correct results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple maths to do this:

```
private static int getLength(int num) {

    int count = 1;

    while (num >= 10) {
        num = num / 10;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java:**
A simple Java code like the below will also works fine..!

```
int num = sc.nextInt();    
int b=Integer.toString(num).length();
```

**C++**

```
to_string(num).length()
```

**C**

```
count = 0    
while (num != 0) {
       num /= 10;   
       count++;
        }
```